# How To Filter Hough Lines For Multi-lane Detection?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, hough-transform, houghlinesp

I am using HoughTransformP to do lane detection in OpenCV C++.

My sequence of steps for line detection is basic and goes as follows:

```
1. Bird Eye View of image
2. Grayscale image
3. Guassian Blur image
4. Canny Edge detection
5. HoughTransformP canny image
6. Filter out horizontal lines based on the slope
```

The output after canny edge detection is:

[image]

**The problem here is HougLinesP gives multiple lines, not just the lanes.** The output looks something similar to this:

[image]

I am trying to obtain something like this:

[image]

**How do I filter the clutter of lines and draw only lane lines?**

Comment: you can always try to threshold the image to get yellow/white colors only, this way the lines detected will be from the lanes

Comment: @api55 I tried thresholding too but I still see clutter of lines at each lane.  And mere thresholding doesn't work in all scenarios. Take an example where you have **road divider** (which will be white/yellow and black) in your frame and HoughLinesP gives bunch of lines on that too. How can I just get one line like shown in the image at the end of the question?

Comment: @AkritiRao are you able to draw the blue line segments showed in the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wKPD.png ?

Comment: It would seem that the lines that should go together are almost parallel with each other.

Comment: @AlessandroJacopson Yes, I am able to do that. I get cluster of lines at each and every lane.

Comment: @DanMašek Yes, the lines are parallel in Bird Eye View of the image.

Comment: @AkritiRao So maybe you can try to implement the algorithm I suggest in the answer and see the results.

Answer (score 1):

The outline of a possible algorithm:

1. Cluster the line segments: referring for example at the following image you should be able to label each segment with `1`, `2`, `3` or `4`.
2. For each cluster find an "average line".

[image]

Cast the line segments in *Hessian normal form* 
`x*cos(beta)+y*sin(beta)-p=0` where `p` is the distance between the segment and the origin and `beta` is the angle you see in the following image:

[image]

You can cluster the line segments with some proper machine learning technique for example with an input feature vector `[p, beta]`, then you can find the "average line" for example averaging both `b` and `beta`.
Say you have the two segments `[p_1, beta_1]` and `[p_2, beta_2]` belonging to the same cluster, the average segment is `[(p_1+p_2)/2, (beta_1+beta_2)/2]`.